# Using an Intent to open a Tab, from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, tabs

I have 4 Tabs in a particular activity, and I have another activity where I would like to open one of the Tabs

```
private void setupTabIcons() {

    ImageView tabOne = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wall);
    //setImageAlpha(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
    // this is the tab I want to open 
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    ImageView tabTwo = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blog);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

    ImageView tabThree = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_special_feature);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

    ImageView tabFour = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabFour.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
}
```

I want to open tabOne inside here, this code is in another activity

```
 if (extras.get("NAME").equals("Post ")) {
       //I want to open tabOne here, when you click here it should open tab one from here
    }
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "I have another activity where I would like to open one of the Tabs" means. Do you mean that you want the same UI in the one tab that you also have in this other activity? If so, implement that tab as a fragment and use it in both places.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just want to click from my second activity and it opens the first tab (tabOne) thats all.

Comment: That simply repeats what you have in the question, and I do not know what you mean by that.

Comment: am not sure, if am clear enough. But what i mean is, I have 2 activity, Activity A and Activity B, Activity A has 4 tabs (1,2,3,4) and In activity B I want to use an Intent to open one of the Tab, which is Tab 1.